# Soap web service schema location can't be found in wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, spring, soap, wsdl

My web service is as a jar file and being used as a plugin from another web application, so I have only one web.xml in the main web app and give referance to my dispatcher servlet, and it works good, but my problem is when I want to use it by using its wsdl file by a soap client(soapUI can not find the schemas in the wsdl)

this is how my servlet.xml looks like in the jar file;

```
<bean id="schema" class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema">
    <property name="xsd" value="classpath:/resources/xwebservice/schemas/Request.xsd" />
</bean>

<bean id="mwsid"
    class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.SimpleWsdl11Definition">
    <constructor-arg value="classpath:/resources/xwebservice/spring-ws.wsdl"/>
</bean>
```

And this is how my wsdl file looks like it's name is spring-ws.wsdl

```
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xsd:import namespace="http://www.mywebsite.com/xml/webservice"                      
            schemaLocation="/resources/xwebservice/schemas/Request.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
```

This can not find the request.xsd schema when I try to access my webservice using a soap client(soapUI) by showing my wsdl url address, which is;

```
http://localhost:8080/mwp/mws/mwsid.wsdl
```

The wsdl and schema files are on different folders in my web service plugin jar, where is my mistake? I can expose the wsdl in browser by the url above, but soap client cant find the schemas in the path.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SimpleXsdSchema exposes the schema as the name of the bean plus .xsd (in this case schema.xsd).
So you have to update the WSDL to point to it:

```
schemaLocation="schema.xsd"
```